# IFNULL in nested select statement mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return a message when there is no row found in a `nested SELECT` statement like so. In this case, when there is no `Lake` in a row, the return message is 'no lake found'. I tried `IFNULL` but it return nothing when there is no lake.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(concat_ws(', ', Lake_name, 
                                    IFNULL(Area, 'not available'),                             
                                    IFNULL(Altitude, 'not available'), 
                                    IFNULL(Depth, 'not available'), 
                                    IFNULL(River_outflow, 'not available')
                             ) SEPARATOR '; ')
From LAKE WHERE IFNULL(Lake_name, 'no lakes found') IN
                      (SELECT  Lake FROM LOCATION where County IN 
                      (SELECT County FROM CITY WHERE City_name='$userinput')) GROUP BY NULL;";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should select this way

```
  SELECT CASE when Lake_name is null then 'no lakes found' else 
       GROUP_CONCAT(concat_ws(', ', Lake_name, 
                                      IFNULL(Area, 'not available'),                             
                                      IFNULL(Altitude, 'not available'), 
                                      IFNULL(Depth, 'not available'), 
                                      IFNULL(River_outflow, 'not available')
                               ) SEPARATOR '; ') END my_lake
  From LAKE 
  WHERE LAKE_name  IN  (SELECT  Lake_name FROM LOCATION where County IN 
                        (SELECT County FROM CITY WHERE City_name='$userinput')) 
  OR LAKE_name is null ;
```

Comment: it works but there's still no message return; I even change it to "or LAKE.Lake_name is NULL GROUP BY Lake_name, Area, Altitude, Depth, River_outflow" at then end

Comment: I'm sorry i have used wrong lake instead of lake_name  .. i have slightly update the answer  with lake_name ..  could be that the alias  don't work right so i change the alias for column name in my_lake .. let me know